# WKHTMLTOPDF path in ROR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wicked_pdf gem for HTML to PDF conversion. As per the descriptions in Github, I installed everything correctly. But I am getting a runtime error -

**RuntimeError (Bad wkhtmltopdf's path: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:46:in `create**

```
`44 @count = Item.count(:qty)
45  @temp = Item.where(:received => true).count()
46  render  :pdf => "Bill" ,
47  :template => 'orders/create.pdf.erb', # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
48  page_height:  100,
49  page_width:   80`
```

and wkhtmltopdf is installed in my system at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

It is specified that the path for wkhtmltopdf should be where it's already installed.

I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the source of wkhtmltopdf it looks like all it is doing is running File.exists? on that path:

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/56aa1a195d65eaaf33fbd0254e1e7df99ce1fd1c/lib/wicked_pdf.rb#L41

So we gotta double check the assumption that wkhtmltopdf is correctly installed at `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Could you give a bit more information? Just to verify, what is the output of `which wkhtmltopdf`

And when you run `wkhtmltopdf -V` in the console, what do you get?

You could try specifying the path in the configuration (in an initializer as mentioned in the wkhtmltopdf readme) just to see if that makes a difference too.

And lastly you could move the executable to a different directory, and then specify that in the initializer to see if it maybe has something to do with folder permissions.

Comment: Output of which wkhtmltopdf is - /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf and of wkhtmltopdf -V is wkhtmltopdf 0.9.6

Comment: Hmm, im as baffled as you are. I think as a last debugging attempt you could try specifying the path explicitly and/or moving the executable to a different location.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried specifying the path in an initializer? ({rails.root}/config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb) ex..

```
WICKED_PDF = {
    :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'#should be whatever your version is called
}
```

Answer (score 3):

wkhtmltopdf will install into `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` but it's expected at `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`.

To fix it just create symbolic link as (probably you will need to use sudo):

`ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem. Try reinstalling gem and also install library to support that gem.
here are the links to install that library in mac and ubuntu:

[unable to install wkhtmltopdf with patched qt in ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765698/unable-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-with-patched-qt-in-ubuntu-16-04)

http://macappstore.org/wkhtmltopdf/