# unable to install wkhtmltopdf with patched qt in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

wkhtmltopdf with patched qt  pkg is not available for ubuntu 16.04 .so i am install 14.04 pkg which is install without patched qt but it need it with patched qt. I also tried with static version but it give some compilation
error

Answer (score 27):

The patched version of `wkhtmltopdf` is not present in the Ubuntu repository. You can [download it](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) from the project website if you want. But they still don't have a `.deb` file for Xenial Xerus, so you need to download the binary file and install the dependencies (`libxrender1 fontconfig xvfb`) manually.

Here is a script that installs the patched version from the project website:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxrender1 fontconfig xvfb
wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz -P /tmp/
cd /opt/
sudo tar xf /tmp/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
sudo ln -s /opt/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

**Edit** [16/06/2017]: wkhtmltopdf releases were moved to GitHub due to instability of their servers. I've updated my answer to provide the right path to download the latest release.

Comment: For my ubuntu 16.04 container, I had to modify the last line of the sequence to::   

    `sudo ln -s /opt/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: Is there a simple verification test?

Comment: I downloaded it from `https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz`

Comment: Downloading from `https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org` just redirects to the github releases url, so either is fine.

Comment: For those of us who tried doing an apt-get install originally, it's best to clean that up first with: ```sudo apt-get remove --purge wkhtmltopdf```

Answer (score 10):

For version 0.12.4 (latest on 15 Jan 2017)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxrender1 fontconfig xvfb
wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz -P /tmp/
cd /opt/
sudo tar xf /tmp/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
sudo ln -s /opt/wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: Please be informed that `gna.org` has been closed now. so you should download precompiled binaries from https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org . Please see
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3390#issuecomment-287982282

Answer (score 1):

I ran @matheus-marchini's script to install the patched version a while back and just came back to get the instructions again - however, I discovered that in the interim, the hosting site Gna! has shut down. After a little search, I was able to replace the link directly from the source, updating the command as follows:

```
wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz -P /tmp/
```

If you want the most recent version (per @afzal-hossain's answer), it would be:

```
wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz -P /tmp/
```

I would have written this as a comment instead of as an "answer" but I do not have enough reputation yet to do that. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf_0.12.2.4-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltopdf_0.12.2.4-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this version is not patched with Qt. It works fine if you don't need any extra features, like headers, footers, margins, etc. Otherwise it's better to download the binary from the project's website.